# stains on the labels using pdf format in matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

below is my code to generate a horizontal bar plot in `matplotlib`. After the execution, the plot is supposed to be saved in `pdf` format, however I got stains on the words and labels.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

p1 = ax.barh(0.2, 0.44, color='0', height=0.4)
p2 = ax.barh(0.2, 0.56,  left=.44, color='0.9', height=0.4)

ax.barh(1.0, 0.489, color='0', height=0.4)
ax.barh(1.0, 0.511,  left=0.489, color='0.9', height=0.4)

ax.set_ylim([0,1.6])
ax.set_yticks([0.4, 1.2])
ax.set_yticklabels(['80%\nhomology', '40%\nhomology'], fontsize=14)

ax.text(0.2, 0.4, "%d%%" % (44), ha='center',va='center',color='0.9', fontsize=14)
ax.text(0.7, 0.4, "%d%%" % (56), ha='center',va='center', color='0', fontsize=14)
ax.text(0.2, 1.2, "%d%%" % (49), ha='center',va='center', color='0.9', fontsize=14)
ax.text(0.7, 1.2, "%d%%" % (51), ha='center',va='center',color='0', fontsize=14)

plt.legend( (p1[0], p2[0]), ('Physics-based contribution', 'Evolution-based contribution'),loc='center',frameon=False)

ax.set_xticklabels(['0%', '20%','40%','60%','80%', '100%'], fontsize=14)
fig.savefig('contribution.pdf', dpi=100)
```

1. Anybody knows how to remove those stains?
2. The y axis label is too long to display completely(*ho* is missing), how to get around this problem?

[image]

Comment: That's a known bug. Which version of matplotlib do you have? If you safe it as png you won't have the ugly signs in your percent characters.

Comment: @miindlek reference on the know bug?

Comment: And I can not reproduce this on the master branch.

Comment: @tcaswell Have a look at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1211 . But it is fixed for a while now, that's why you can't reproduce it on the master branch. This is why I wanted to know which version the OP uses.

Comment: @miindlek Thanks (pre-dates when I started following mpl bugs).